# Possible to add Linked file in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to add an existing file (.vb file) as a linked file in the following version of Visual Studio to a 'website' solution?

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1

Installed Edition: Professional

With the Add button on the 'Add Existing Item' dialog i don't see linked file option - only 'Add' & 'show previous versions'

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a website, NOT a web application, probably not. Website is just a directory with files. 
To add a linked file you may create a [symlink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx)

Comment: Its a website, not a web application.  thanks - clears that up for me.